# How to create directories and sub directories efficiently and elegantly in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory, directory-structure, python-os

I am trying to create a bunch of directories and sub directories at a specific location in my PC. My process is something like this:

1. Check if there's any directory with the same directory name. Skip if so.
2. If not, create the directory and the pre-defined sub directories under that directory.

This is the code I came up with using `os` module:

```
def Test():
    main_dir = ["FolderA", "FolderB"] 
    common_dir = ["SubFolder1", "SubFolder2", "SubFolder3"]

    for dir1 in main_dir:
        if not os.path.isdir(dir1):
            for dir2 in common_dir:
                os.makedirs("%s/%s" %(dir1,dir2))
```

I am wondering if there's any better way to do this very same task (probably shorter, more efficient and more pythonic)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python follows the philosophy

> It is better to ask for forgiveness than to ask for permission.

So rather than checking `isdir`, you would simply catch the exception thrown if the leaf directory already exists:

```
def Test():
    main_dir = ["FolderA", "FolderB"] 
    common_dir = ["SubFolder1", "SubFolder2", "SubFolder3"]

    for dir1 in main_dir:
        for dir2 in common_dir:
            try: os.makedirs(os.path.join(dir1,dir2))
            except OSError: pass
```

You can also replace string interpolation `"%s/%s" %(dir1,dir2)` with `os.path.join(dir1, dir2)`

Another more succinct way is to do the cartesian product instead of using two nested for-loops:

```
for dir1, dir2 in itertools.product(main_dir, common_dir):
    try: os.makedirs(os.path.join(dir1,dir2))
    except OSError: pass
```

Comment: This will treat existing directories and a failed attempt to create the directory (such as lacking permissions) the same way. You should check that `error.errno == 17` (17 meaning that the directory already exists) and rethrow the exception if it's not.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
import os
from itertools import starmap

def Test():
    main_dir = ["FolderA", "FolderB"] 
    common_dir = ["SubFolder1", "SubFolder2", "SubFolder3"]

    map(os.makedirs, starmap(os.path.join, zip(main_dir, common_dir)))
```

And if we're worried about `os.makedirs()` throwing errors:

```
import os
from itertools import starmap

def safe_makedirs(*args):
    try:
        return os.makedirs(*args)
    except:
        pass  # Ignore errors; for example if the paths already exist!

def Test():
    main_dir = ["FolderA", "FolderB"] 
    common_dir = ["SubFolder1", "SubFolder2", "SubFolder3"]

    map(safe_makedirs, starmap(os.path.join, zip(main_dir, common_dir)))
```